# 特定の画像でテンソルフローのグレイスケール変換を使うとエラーが発生する

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, 画像, google-colaboratory

グーグルドライブから画像を読み込んで加工するプログラムを書いたいたところ、特定の画像でエラーが発生しました。ほかの画像だと問題なく加工できたのですが、この画像で実行すると下記のエラーが発生してしまいます。どうやら読み込み、テンソル化までは問題なく行っているようです。
使用言語は*python*で、実行環境は*google colaboratory*です。
テンソルフローのバージョンは2.0.0です。

どのようにすればこのエラーは解消しますか。

※当方このサイトにあまり慣れていないため、質問方法や記載方法がおかしかったら是非指摘していただけると助かります。

---

### エラーメッセージ

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-242afefc9006> in <module>()
  1 pre_data = tf.image.resize(pre_data,[500,500])
----> 2 pre_data = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(pre_data)
  3 pre_data = np.asarray(pre_data)
  4 pre_data = np.squeeze(pre_data)
  5 pre_data.shape
 ------------------------------->>4 frames<<----------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [250000,4], In[1]: [3,1] [Op:MatMul] name: rgb_to_grayscale/Tensordot/MatMul/
```

---

### 問題コード

※`print()`などは省略しています。また、本来のColaboratory上のプログラムではセルに分かれているところを詰めて書いています(上手な書き方があれば教えて下さい)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

path = "/content/drive/My Drive/for_MikuChecker"

img = np.asarray(Image.open(path + "/run_check/yes/48911351_p0.png"))
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)          # TensorShape([992, 622, 4])
size= h if h<w else w                    # w,h = (622, 992)
pre_data = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(img,int((h-size)/2),int((w-size)/2),size,size)
pre_data = tf.image.resize(pre_data,[500,500])
pre_data = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(pre_data)
pre_data = np.asarray(pre_data)
pre_data = np.squeeze(pre_data)
pre_data.shape
```

**エラー発生場所**

> pre_data = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(pre_data)

**使用した画像**
[image: エラーが発生した画像]

[この画像の転載元(本家様)](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=48911351)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのミクの画像は著作権周り大丈夫でしょうか？　ご自身が著作者でない場合無断転載扱いになる可能性があるため、少なくとも引用要件を満たすような形にしておいた方が安心かと思います。質問は後からでも「編集」できますので、ご一考くださいませ。

Comment: 浅慮でした...。元画像へのリンクを付けました。このプログラムは商用ではなく、製作者様が商用作品以外は転載してかまわないとおっしゃっているので、要件は満たしているはずです。これからは注意します。

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow のドキュメントによると tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale 関数は、以下のように最後の次元が ３ であることが必要と書かれています.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale

```
Args:

    images: The RGB tensor to convert. Last dimension must have size 3 and should contain RGB values.
```

しかし問題となっているソースコードを見ると

```
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)          # TensorShape([992, 622, 4])
```

となっており最後の次元が 4 となっていますのでエラーが発生していると思います。問題の画像は RGB ではなく RGBA 画像のようです。 上記のコードを以下のように RGB の３つのチャンネルだけを使用してテンソルを作成すれば、ひとまずエラーは回避できるかと思います。(アルファチャンネルなどが設定されていた場合は別途対応が必要です)

```
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img[:,:,:3])
```